# Why 'value' can be used as a variable, when it is a keyword in C#?

Tags: c#

If `value` is the *keyword* in *C#* and *keywords* cannot be used as a name (*identifier*) of a *variable*, *class*, *interface*, etc.

How can `value` still be used as a variable?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int value =2;            
    Console.WriteLine(value);       
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, C# stopped having new reserved words since C# 2. Any new keywords after C# 2, are in fact just contextual keywords, not reserved words. So even this works in latest C#: `int from = 42; for(int i = from - 1; i >= 0; --i) {`. This too works in latest C#:  `int async = 42; Console.WriteLine(async);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value) is a *Contextual Keyword*, which means it depends on the context, it's not a *Reserved Word*.

> The *contextual keyword* `value` is used in the set *accessor* in ordinary
> *property* declarations. It is similar to an input parameter on a
> *method*. The word `value` references the value that client code is
> attempting to assign to the *property*.

[Contextual Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#contextual-keywords)

> A *contextual keyword* is used to provide a specific meaning in the
> code, but it is not a *reserved* word in C#.

Here is a list of keywords that are reserved and will need to be prefixed with the `@` symbol

[C# Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)

> *Keywords* are predefined, reserved *identifiers* that have special
> meanings to the *compiler*. They cannot be used as *identifiers* in your
> program unless they include `@` as a prefix. For example, `@if` is a valid
> identifier, but `if` is not because if is a *keyword*.